# Retrieving amazon book recommendation

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does any one know how to retrieve Amazon book recommendation like what [BookSeer](http://bookseer.com/.) does.
I visited Amazon book service page but I am overwhelmed by the amount of information in it. I could not seem to figure out which amazon webservice that I can use to retrieve Amazon book recommendation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

They're probably using [Amazon's Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).